# I want to split row on basis of comma (,) but expect comma in substring

Tags: java, string, split

String -

```
Bank of India,1.19E+13,06-02-2015,"BY CLG/237336/560015089/CAB,IND",140980,C,,140980,2,NA,N
```

I want to split row on basis of comma (,) but don't consider comma within string.
I want output in array like :

```
Bank of India
1.19E+13,06-02-2015
BY CLG/237336/560015089/CAB,IND
140980
C
140980
2
NA
N
```

but in string `BY CLG/237336/560015089/CAB,IND` comma problem; has anyone faced issue like that before?

Some strings e.g. -

```
State Bank of India,30902918138,01-06-2015,DEP TFR TRF FROM 3199860044304 RTGS UTIBR52015060100038810 MOHAN SYNTHETICS,2348386,C,-79046734.87,2348386,6,F04,Y

Bank of India,1.19E+13,06-01-2015,RTGS/CHOPRA ENTERPRISES,330963,C,,330963,1,NA,N

Bank of India,1.19E+13,06-02-2015,"BY CLG/237336/560015089/CAB,IND",140980,C,,140980,2,NA,N
```

Comment: is this pattern is same for all string?

Comment: yes that pattern for all string

Comment: split string based on `,` , then concat string of index 1 and 2 .

Comment: but we can't consider user will enter only one coma in string

Comment: don't use comma to separate fields. or replace all user commas for something else. in the end replace the something else by comma again

Answer (score 1):

If you can use Apache Commons then the method [split](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#split-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) in StringUtils is what you're looking for,  for instance:

```
String[] myString =StringUtils.split("string 1, string2", "," );
```

> Splits the provided text into an array, separators specified. This is
>   an alternative to using StringTokenizer.
>
> The separator is not included in the returned String array. Adjacent
>   separators are treated as one separator. For more control over the
>   split use the StrTokenizer class.
>
> A null input String returns null. A nullseparatorChars splits on
>   whitespace.

```
StringUtils.split(null, *) = null StringUtils.split("", *) = [] StringUtils.split("abc def", null) = ["abc", "def"] StringUtils.split("abc def", " ") = ["abc", "def"] StringUtils.split("abc def", " ") = ["abc", "def"] StringUtils.split("ab:cd:ef", ":") = ["ab", "cd", "ef"]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to use the external library only for that, there is the way using Regex to define where the partial should be and get them.

Let's assume your Sting can contain empty fields between commas.

```
([\w ]+),+(.*?),+"(.*?)",+(.+?),+(\w),+(\d+),+(\d),+(\w+),+(\w)
```

See the demo at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aYw2G5/2).